# How to find the alpha parameter of beta distribution

Tags: r, mle, beta-distribution

I am trying to find the MLE estimate of alpha of a beta distribution given beta = 1. 
I tried using maxlogL from the estimationtools package but g

```
x <- rbeta(n = 1000, shape1 = 0.7, shape2 = 1)

alpha_hat <- maxlogL(x = x, dist = "dbeta", fixed = list(shape2 = 1), lower = (0), upper = (1), link = list(over = "shape1", fun = "log_link"))
summary(alpha_hat)
```

For the normal distributions the following computations do give me an estimate of sd.

```
x <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 160, sd = 6)
theta_1 <- maxlogL(x = x, dist = 'dnorm', control = list(trace = 1),link = list(over = "sd", fun = "log_link"),
                 fixed = list(mean = 160))
summary(theta_1)
```

Could someone point out the mistake in the first piece of code?

Comment: It is not very clear what your problem is with the first piece of code, it seems your sentence got cropped for some reason "... from the estimationtools package but g" please update your question so the community can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know.  I'm going to be lazy and do it a different way I'm more familiar with:

```
library(bbmle)
m <- mle2(x~dbeta(shape1=exp(loga),shape2=1), 
        data=data.frame(x), start=list(loga=0))
## estimate (back-transformed)
exp(coef(m)) ## 0.6731152
## profile confidence interval (back-transformed)
exp(confint(m))
##     2.5 %    97.5 %
## 0.6322529 0.7157005
```

Setting up a simple bootstrap function ...

```
bootfun <- function() {
    newx <- sample(x,size=length(x),replace=TRUE)
    newm <- update(m, data=data.frame(x=newx))
    return(coef(newm))
}
set.seed(101)
bootsamp <- replicate(500, bootfun())
exp(quantile(bootsamp, c(0.025, 0.975)))
##      2.5%     97.5% 
## 0.6533478 0.7300200
```

In fact, for this case the (very quick) Wald confidence intervals are probably fine ...

```
exp(confint(m,method="quad"))
##     2.5 %    97.5 % 
## 0.6462591 0.7315456
```

Comment: When I reproduced your first block of code I got different and nonsense estimates ad confints.

Comment: I think I forgot to exponentiate.